# How to resolve nrwl storybook configuration error?

Tags: angular, storybook, nrwl

Trying to setup storybook for my angular project using nrwl configurations for storybook. When I try to run the command to generate stories for the project, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined

This is the command that I'm trying to run:
`ng g @nrwl/angular:storybook-configuration project-name`
where project-name is the name of the library inside libs folder with several components inside it. The library on its own works fine in the application which makes me believe there's no problem with the library's configuration by itself.

Here is the version configuration for the project:
`"@angular/cli": "^8.3.23"`,
`"@nrwl/angular": "^8.11.1"`

Is there a way I can possibly debug this error? When I tried to add `--verbose` in front of the command it says `Unknown option: '--verbose'`.

Comment: You can use `--debug` instead of `--verbose`.
I'm having the same issue and could narrow it down. But I still don't understand it and it looks to me like a bug. I will report it to Nrwl and get back here with the link to this report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you should have the same issue as I do, then it may be a bug.

I reported it on [GitHub](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2521). There you can also find a workaround, in case you're having an issue influenced by the same problem.